# Method or data member not found compile issue

Tags: vb6, datamember

I have a VB6 project that I didn't create but I have to update, when I go to make the exe I get a compile error: Method or data member not found, and it points too "SCom1.FileReceive" in the code below. When I look at the Main form, the SCom1 control is a PictureBox.

This code has been working for the last 5 years but I don't know why SCom1 is a picturebox, or why I'm getting the error, is it a reference? SCom1 to me looks like a MSComm function? Let me know if anyone has any ideas, I just don't know VB enough to know how to troubleshoot this. Thanks

```
If SCom1.FileReceive = True Then   
WriteToLog (Now() & " FileReceive was true, now false")
    SCom1.FileReceive = False
End If
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The machine which you have opened the code doesn't have the mscomm32.ocx file or the ocx file not registered properly.

When vb cannot reference an ocx, it'll convert the relevant control to a picture box control.

What you have to do is, close the project without saving. Then open system32 folder and check for mscomm32.ocx file. If the file is not there then you have to download that from the intenet. The register the file using regsvr32 command in command prompt.

After this you can open the vb6 project and start working.

=========================================================

EDIT : Included the update in the comments to the answer, this will help other users in the future... :-)

if the method name doesn't look familiar to a known ocx file (in this case the `SCom1`.FileReceive), the missing component can be a custom ocx file.

So check on the working machine or in project folder whether there are any ocx file exists in the relevant name (in this case `SCom.ocx`).

if there is a file exists in such name, register that file using regsvr32 (if not registered), then add that to toolbox, then replace the picture box control with the relevant control (make sure the name tally).

Comment: So MSComm32.Ocx will not work for my project I need to have MSComm.Ocx?

Comment: Not exactly. You need to have mscomm32.ocx file. This will work with your project. Check whether you have mscomm32.ocx in your system32 folder.

Comment: I do have it, and the machine it runs on only has mscomm32.ocx, no mscomm.ocx on either my machine or the client

Comment: :-) that's Wat I said. So you have ocx file. Now check on the toolbox in vb6 whether you can refer that control. If it's not there in toolbox you need add that from add control menu

Comment: Ok it wasn't in the toolbox, I did add it, I replaced the picture box with a MSComm component, saved it, closed it, reopened it, tryed to create the exe, and it seems to keep giving the same error. Is there something else I'm missing, a build feature, or another reference?

Comment: Did u make sure the newly added com control Name is changed to the old name of the picture box?

Comment: Ok so the MSComm component I added has some of the features called in the project, but FileReceive is not one of its functions, hence why I still get the error, do you know what control would have that function along with FileTransmit, and JobProcessing?

Comment: I asume this is custom ocx file. Check on the woking machine that there are ocx file in the name of scom.

Comment: Yes there was, it compiles now, at least past that error, thank you so much for your help no way would I of figured that out without you.

Comment: I have come across a similar issue.

Comment: I have also come across a similar issue while making an exe.
error or line,
crvwrMain.EnableExportButton.
The  MSComm.Ocx is present in the SysWOW64 folder..

Comment: worked ! 
I just added a 'CrystalActiveXReportViewer' control on the form and named it 'crvwrMain'.